# I am experiencing strange font problems with urxvt in Xwin

Tags: cygwin, xorg, xming

It appears that characters are shifted over one pixel to the left. I am experiencing this problem in multiple fonts. I have previously not experienced this problem.

Here is a picture of the behavior in Cygwin's Xwin:
[image: -]

Here is a picture of the desired behavior (Xming)
[image: -]

The problem occurs in both multiwindow and windowed mode. I cannot use Xming in this case.